# Error using custom Skipper body parser configuration

Tags: sails.js, sails-skipper

I'm using sails version 0.10.5. I have the bodyParser set like so in `http.js`:

```
bodyParser: require('skipper')({
  limit: 52428800
})
```

And I keep getting this error when starting the server:

````
error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at _parseHTTPBody (/var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/skipper/index.js:49:19)
    at /var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/http/middleware/defaults.js:104:28
    at module.exports (/var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/http/middleware/defaults.js:144:7)
    at loadExpress (/var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/http/initialize.js:103:65)
    at /var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/http/index.js:190:18
    at /var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/after.js:91:14
    at /var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:232:13
    at /var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:119:25
    at /var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:24:16
    at /var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:229:17
    at /var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:516:34
    at handlerFn (/var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/after.js:78:13)
    at /var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:511:21
    at /var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:227:13
    at /var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:111:13
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each (/var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)
    at async.each (/var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:110:9)
    at _asyncMap (/var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:226:9)
    at Object.map (/var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:204:23)
    at _parallel (/var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:509:20)
    at Object.async.parallel (/var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:539:9)
    at Sails.emitter.after (/var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/after.js:89:11)
    at Hook.initialize (/var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/http/index.js:189:15)
    at Hook.bound [as initialize] (/var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
    at /var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/index.js:132:16
    at /var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:425:17
    at /var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:419:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at _each (/var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:24)
    at Immediate.taskComplete (/var/www/testapp-backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:418:13)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17) [TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined]

error: Encountered an error when trying to use configured bodyParser.
error: Usually, this means that it was installed incorrectly.
error: A custom bodyParser can be configured without calling the wrapper function- e.g.:
```
bodyParser: require("connect-busboy")
```
error: Alternatively, if you need to provide options:
```
bodyParser: {
fn: require("connect-busboy"),
options: {/* ... */}
}
```
````

There are no errors there after. What am I doing wrong? I tried following the instructions of the error but with skipper I'm not able to upload files to S3 greater than just a few mb's. I tried this and it doesn't work:

```
bodyParser: {
fn: require("skipper"),
options: {limit: 52428800}
}
```

that is as per the message above.

Comment: (see https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper/issues/157)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to a bug in the default `bodyParser` setting in Sails < 0.12, the normal method of configuring the middleware won't work.  The easiest solution is to simply replace `bodyParser` in the middleware order with another, custom middleware name and configure *that* instead, e.g.:

```
module.exports.http = {

  middleware: {

    // The order in which middleware should be run for HTTP request.
    // (the Sails router is invoked by the "router" middleware below.)
    order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      // 'bodyParser', // <-- don't add the "bodyParser" middleware to the stack
      'skipper',   // <-- instead use this "custom" middleware
      'handleBodyParserError',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ],

    // Configure Skipper
    skipper: require('skipper')({
      limit: 52428800
    })

  }
}
```